# Learning to angular: ng-view not loading, why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The page of this app just loads blank. I i searched the problem for hours and still can't find the problem. Angular is 1.3.5 and Angular-route is v1.2.28.

This is index.html:

```js
<html ng-app="myApp">
 <head> 
  <script src="js/angulark.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="js/angular-routek.js"></script>
  <script>
   var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
   
    myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider
      .when('/',
       {
        controller: 'MainController',
        templateUrl: 'views/nameView.html';      
       }) 
      .when('/cityView',
       {
        controller: 'MainController',
        templateUrl: 'views/cityView.html';      
       })
      .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    }); 
   
    myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.customers = [
      { name: 'Andre Queiroz', city: 'Rio de Janeiro' },
      { name: 'Fulano', city: 'Sao Paulo'}, 
      { name: 'Beltrano', city: 'Curitiba' }
     ];
    
     $scope.addCustomer() = function () {
      $scope.customers.push( 
       { name: $scope.newCustomer.name, city: $scope.newCustomer.city } 
      );
     };   
    }]);  
  </script>
  <title>Meu Aplicativo</title>
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <div>
   <!-- Placeholder for views -->
   <div ng-view> </div>    
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is nameView.html

```js
<div class="container"> 
 <div ng-controller="MainController">  
  <div>
   <h2>View 1</h2>
   Name: <input type="text" ng-model="filter.name"/> 
  </div>
  <br />  
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:filter.name | orderBy:'city'">{{cust.name | uppercase}} - {{cust.city}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div 
  
  <div>
   <p>Customer name:</p>
   <input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.name" />
   <p>Customer city:</p>
   <input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.city" />
   <button ng-click="addCustomer()">Add customer </button>
   <a href="#/view2">View 2</a>
  </div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

The cityView.html is the same but with no addCustomer stuff. I was dividing into module file and so on, but i put it in one file to see if it worked.

Comment: what is the `filter:filter.name`, can you try removing this from the `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Fix your syntax errors first, then it would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually doing well. Most of erros are syntax.

> Error 1:  Remove **;** from templateUrl inside **$routeProvider.when()**

Eq. templateUrl: 'views/cityView.html'

> Error 2: Can't have parentheses to create a method with this sintaxe 
>   $scope: Eq. $scope.newfunction = function() {...}

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>  
        <script src="js/angulark.min.js"></script>  
        <script src="js/angular-routek.js"></script>
        <script>
            var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

                myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
                    $routeProvider
                        .when('/',
                            {
                                controller: 'MainController',
                                templateUrl: 'views/nameView.html'                      
                            })  
                        .when('/cityView',
                            {
                                controller: 'MainController',
                                templateUrl: 'views/cityView.html'                      
                            })
                        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
                }); 

                myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
                    $scope.customers = [
                        { name: 'Andre Queiroz', city: 'Rio de Janeiro' },
                        { name: 'Fulano', city: 'Sao Paulo'}, 
                        { name: 'Beltrano', city: 'Curitiba' }
                    ];

                    $scope.addCustomer = function () {
                        $scope.customers.push( 
                            { name: $scope.newCustomer.name, city: $scope.newCustomer.city } 
                        );
                    };          
                }]);        
        </script>
        <title>Meu Aplicativo</title>
    </head> 
    <body>  
        <div>
            <!-- Placeholder for views -->
            <div ng-view> </div>                
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

There're some HTML errors in your view. Make sure to validate your HTML.

> Error: In the line 11, you must fix from `</div` to `</div>`

Also, you don't need to add a controller. You already added on your config:

> Remove it from your view: From `<div
>   ng-controller="MainController">` to `<div>`

*Not required, but best practice*

On your last line, there's a spare `</div>`, get rid of it:

```
<div class="container">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
        <div>
            <h2>View 1</h2>
            Name: <input type="text" ng-model="filter.name"/>
        </div>
        <br />
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:filter.name | orderBy:'city'">{{cust.name | uppercase}} - {{cust.city}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>Customer name:</p>
        <input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.name" />
        <p>Customer city:</p>
        <input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.city" />
        <button ng-click="addCustomer()">Add customer </button>
        <a href="#/view2">View 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

PS: Make sure you check your syntax errors. Using jshint, jslint or even Chrome dev tools / Firebug will help with that. You can set your editor(Sublimelinter for Sublime for example) to use jshint. Or use a IDE like Webstorm which comes with.

Comment: ty very much, helped me a lot. I'm using WebStorm now. The problem is that the code is running normal through WebStorm but loading blank when i just click the index.html. Do you know what it could be?

Comment: Check your browser console. AngularJS has a very nice debugger exceptions. Also you can activate either [jshint](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/jshint.html) or [jslint](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/jslint.html) at Webstorm. Over your mouse on Webstorm bulbs(lamps) and read the warning messages. They'll help you to debug.

Answer (score 2):

There is a mistake in index.html javascript.
Inside `MainController` change your code

```
$scope.addCustomer() = function () {
    $scope.customers.push( 
        { name: $scope.newCustomer.name, city: $scope.newCustomer.city } 
    );
};
```

to

```
$scope.addCustomer= function () {
    $scope.customers.push( 
        { name: $scope.newCustomer.name, city: $scope.newCustomer.city } 
    );
};
```

it should `$scope.addCustomer=` instead of `$scope.addCustomer()=`